# What is this 64-pin chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I have tried to find it on Farnell, Mouser and Alldatasheet, but without any luck. What is it?

[image: The item I know nothing]

Comment: Observation: there appear to be an increasing number of China-only IC's.  For those IC's, also search AliExpress, Alibaba, etc.

Comment: Related: *[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/)*, *[Should we keep component identification questions?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6697/)*, and *[Identification questions getting closed formally](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/)*. Includes: ***"Type out any text on the part."***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *Can anybody tell me what is it?*

Quite likely an [AF9013 from Afa Technologies](http://www.datasheet-pdf.com/PDF/AF9013-Datasheet-AfaTechnologies-705979): -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's an IC.

Afa Technologies AF9013S-L2 DVB-T COFDM Demodulator.

Likely manufactured in 2006 week 35.